# During the training of the language model, an error occurs: torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, torch

During the second iteration of the finetuning of the language model, an error occurs:

```
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, 
                                            num_warmup_steps=steps_per_epoch*1, 
                                            num_training_steps=steps_per_epoch*NUM_EPOCHS)

print("======================= Start pretraining ==============================")

pretrain(model=model,
         train_iter=train_iter,
         valid_iter=valid_iter,
         optimizer=optimizer,
         scheduler=scheduler,
         num_epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)


NUM_EPOCHS = 12
print("======================= Start training =================================")
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=2e-6)
scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, 
                                            num_warmup_steps=steps_per_epoch*2, 
                                            num_training_steps=steps_per_epoch*NUM_EPOCHS)

train(model=model, 
      train_iter=train_iter, 
      valid_iter=valid_iter, 
      optimizer=optimizer, 
      scheduler=scheduler, 
      num_epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

```
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 16.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 2.00 GiB of which 0 bytes is free.
```

Please tell me how to solve the problem?

Changing the batch size, gradient clipping, limit the sequence length, torch.cuda.empty_cache() as well as changing the optimizer parameters and the number of epochs does not change the situation.

Comment: Have you tried to used GoogleColab? I'm afraid 2 GB could be too little to run a fine-tuning

Answer (score 0):

I normally do the following:

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

You can add the above before your `pretrain` and `train`.

If you still get the error, ret reducing the batch size.

You can also try some of the techniques mentioned [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.18.0/en/performance)